# Saddle Point in Matrix

Tags: matrix

Here is the Problem how to find out the Saddle Point inside Matrix.

```
m = {{9, 3, 1, 8, 0},
  {6, 5, 4, 6, 7},
  {2, 4, 4, 3, 8},
  {5, 6, 2, 2, 1}}
```

Comment: Sarath.S, welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange.  Please provide more detail in your question; describe the output you expect and do not rely on us knowing, guessing, or looking up what you want.

Comment: I would use interpolating function and found it's saddle. However I have no idea how do do it in M.

Answer (score 8):

```
SparseArray[
  Rescale /@ m - Rescale /@ Transpose@m\[Transpose] // 
   IntegerPart]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

Comment: Clever, and a nice use of my old friend `"NonzeroPositions"`.

Comment: Do we have a list of these "methods" that work on SparseArray?  If no, I woulnd't mind a question on it.

Comment: @Szabolcs try the standard "Properties" method

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a saddle point of a matrix is an element that is the largest value of its column and also the smallest value of its row, it can be found out like this:

```
m = {{9, 3, 1, 8, 0},
  {6, 5, 4, 6, 7},
  {2, 4, 4, 3, 8},
  {5, 6, 2, 2, 1}}
mt = Transpose[m]
m1 = Boole[With[{min = Min[#]}, # == min & /@ #] & /@ m]
m2 = Boole[With[{max = Max[#]}, # == max & /@ #] & /@ mt]
Position[m1 + Transpose[m2], 2]
```

The answer is position `{2,3}`. It's not a strict maximum of its column, if this is a requirement then there is no saddle point in this matrix.

There may be more elegant ways of doing this, the strategy here is to set max/min elements to one, the rest to zero and add the two matrices together. If the sum of two elements is two, that means that the element in that position was selected as both a maximum and minimum. `Position` lets us find the position of that element.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing Anon, achieving greater clarity not really.

```
r = Flatten /@ Flatten[MapIndexed[Map[
      Function[p, {#2, p}], Position[#, Min@#]] &, m], 1]
```

> `{{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 5}}`

```
c = Flatten /@ Flatten[MapIndexed[Map[
      Function[p, {#2, p}], Position[#, Max@#]] &, Transpose[m]], 1]
```

> `{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}}`

```
Intersection[r, Reverse /@ c]
```

> `{{2, 3}}`